# Removing a dynamically created li from ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I'm using jquery to add and remove bullets on the fly after the DOM is loaded.

Here's the code to add a bullet which works fine:

```
// add bullet
$('#linkedEventList ul').append('<li id=' + datum._id + '>' + datum.headline + ' <a href=javascript:; title=delete onclick=remove(this) class=itemDelete>(x)</a> <a href=/events/' + datum._id + '>(open)</a></li>');
```

Now here's the code to remove the clicked bullet, which works fine in Firefox, but does not work right in Chrome.  In Chrome, the hyperlink is removed and not the parent or li.

```
// remove bullet
//$(link).closest('li').remove();
$(link).parent().remove();
```

Either method above works fine in FireFox, but neither works in Chrome.  Any ideas on the solution?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjgelinas77/CsAJn/14/

Comment: jQuery Remove method should work fine in Chrome, can you post full code or fiddle?

Comment: You should watch your quotes too for example at the title and the onclick, Some browsers could see  that as an problem. And check your console for errors.

Comment: @Delphian here is the jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jjgelinas77/CsAJn/14/)

Comment: @jbabey link comes from: "onclick=remove(this)". It is the hyperlink that was clicked to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a combination of the answers provided.

I removed the onclick in the li, and instead referenced the class being clicked and combined that with 'this' as per below.

```
$('#linkedEventList').on('click', '.itemDelete', function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle that works in both FireFox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jjgelinas77/CsAJn/27/

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using the index of the clicked `<li>`

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').remove();
});
```

Edit: this works as well:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNQTj/2/).

Comment: The li has two links though, each with a different action.  So uses the li index will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mean

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Also, you might want to consider

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

That will go up the DOMtree until it finds a li, if you ever wrap your anchor in another element, the last example wont brake :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following:

```
$('#linkedEventList ul').append('<li id=' + datum._id + '>' + datum.headline + ' <a href=javascript:; title=delete onclick=remove(this) class=itemDelete>(x)</a> <a href=/events/' + datum._id + '>(open)</a></li>');
```

with this:

```
$('#linkedEventList ul').append('<li id=' + datum._id + '>' + datum.headline + ' <a href=javascript:; title=delete class=itemDelete>(x)</a> <a href=/events/' + datum._id + '>(open)</a></li>');

$('#'+datum._id).bind({
   click: function(o) {
      $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.