# Deleting a dynamically created li tag

Tags: jquery

I am working on an html page where a text list is created dynamically upon users' need. I need to make those li's selectable so that they can be deleted as well...How am i supposed to do it?
I tried using the delegate function but it didn't work.
This is the code of how the li is generated...

```
$('#post_btn').click(function() {
    // body...
    var note = $('#textArea').val();
    $('<li>').text(note).prependTo('.notes');
    $('#textArea').val('');
    $('#post_btn').addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: can you include the deleting button event? do you want to delete the li on li click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a dynamically created li from ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323293/removing-a-dynamically-created-li-from-ul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While clicking the `li` element toggle a class and remove `li` which have that class.

```js
$('#post_btn').click(function() {
  var note = $('#textArea').val();
  $('<li>').text(note).prependTo('.notes');
  $('#textArea').val('');
  $('#post_btn').addClass('disabled');
});

// toggle select class while clicking on the li
$('.notes').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('select');
});

// remove the li which have class select
$('#delete').click(function() {
  $('.notes li.select').remove();
});
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="notes"></ul>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>

<button id="post_btn">Add</button>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you posted enough source code to answer this. But if this is the case:
https://jsfiddle.net/7xarmzbt/

```
<ul id='ul'>

</ul>
<button onclick='al();'>
Add li
</button>
<script>
var total=-1;
function al()
{
total++;
document.getElementById('ul').innerHTML+="<li id='li"+total+"' onclick='deleteli("+total+");'>Li #"+total+"</li>";
}
function deleteli(total_2)
{
document.getElementById('li'+total_2).remove();

}
</script>
```

Then

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID').remove();
```

will work for you. In the generation of the li, simply add an id that will change for each li (like my 'total' var, which is not actually the total number of 'li's, but more of the total number added). For reach li, have a delete function that has the id in it, like mine did. Comment on my answer for more help if I assumed wrong.
**JQUERY CODE EQUIVALENT**

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID').remove();
```

is the same as

```
$( "#YOURIDHERE" ).remove();
```

in jquery.

Comment: Edit #1: Fixed 'js fiddle link'.

Comment: I'll add it. I personally prefer javascript.

Comment: Edit #2: Added jquery code equivalent for solution.

Comment: it's not generally necessary to add comments about each edit. If you want, you can fill in the edit reason in the editing page, although I think most people only do that when they're editing someone else's question/answer, not their own.

Comment: Thanks, but when people rant about my question not answering something after someone has asked me to change it, I prefer to have it documented when I changed it in the comments. I'll remember to use the reason in the editing page more though.