# how to remove li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have folllowing funtion:

```
function addPhone()
    {
        var value=  $('#Membership_c_tel').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/cabinet/membership/addPhone',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {'val':value},
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function (r) {
                var val=document.getElementById("Membership_c_tel").value;
                $("#newly_create_tel").append("<li class="+val+">"+document.getElementById("Membership_c_tel").value+"<a href='#' class=''>x</a></li>");
                $('#Membership_c_tel').val('');


            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

    }
```

The function is responsible for adding `<li>` to `<ul id="newly_create_tel ">` when user submit data using inputbox with id=Membership_c_tel. At the same time `<a href="#">x</a>` is also added with `<li>`. The problem is i do not know how to delete specific `<li>` element when x pressed. How can i achieve to it? Help me.

```
$('#newly_create_tel li a').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                });
```

Comment: @prasad: This would remove all. this.parentNode in the click event is what a man wants to delete.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323293/removing-a-dynamically-created-li-from-ul

Comment: add this inside your click function `$(this).parent().remove();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since it's dynamically generated and get `li` using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent) or [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
$('#newly_create_tel').on('click', 'li a', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: in order to prevent unexcepted deletion, I suggest use an extra special selector rather than `li a` here

Comment: @FuXu :  he can use a class to the `a` tag.... something like `delete`.. that would be much better..... I think this answer would give a basic idea :)

Answer (score 1):

inside click function write $(this).parent().remove;
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to create li element and assign click function right after that:

```
var $element = $('</li>).append($('#Membership_c_tel').val());
$element.append('<a/>', {href:'#', text:'x'});
$element.click(function(){
    // closests will be best if you plan to change your html inside li
    $(this).closests('li').remove();
    return false;
});
$element.appendTo($("#newly_create_tel"));
```

You have more controll and you dont use any events when you dont really need them